# Magento 2 API: How to set custom shipping rate for order?

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api, webapi

I'm creating the order via API requests to Magento's REST endpoints. I would like to set a custom shipping rate for the order. I want to preserve the shipping carrier name and method but have a custom amount on the shipping rate which is different from the default. How can I do that?